# What Does The <path> of <blkiotune> meaning?

Tags: disk, libvirt, qos

[the screenshot of libvirt official document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yu3HO.png)

What does the  of  meaning? Is it meaning that the block device of host, or guest?

Answer (score 0):

You can find it at https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#block-i-o-tuning.And all the parameters are set to guest(VM).